# Azure logic apps using post call submitting form data

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am sumitting a form to azure logic app using post requets.
The form is having two paramaeters
1. FileName
2. FileContent

but I am unable to access these parameters in other actions of logic apps.
Is there any such example then please share the link? How to write JSON Schema for such request in Azure logic apps?

Comment: Refer to [Call, trigger, or nest workflows with HTTP endpoints in logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **`@triggerFormDataValue()`** to get form data values, e.g. `@triggerFormDataValue('FileName')` and `@triggerFormDataValue('FileContent')`

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#triggerformdatavalue).

HTH